# uploading image from android through WP REST API

Tags: android, wordpress, loopj

I have a following image upload api which works fine.

```
CURL --user username:password -X POST -H 'Content-Disposition: filename=scarlett-judinna.jpg' --data-binary @'/Volumes/Work/tmp/Dummy Images/image.jpg' http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media
```

Now i want to upload image from android using this api.

I have tried the following process.

```
params.put("image", new ByteArrayInputStream(byte_arr));
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setBasicAuth(username, password);
client.addHeader("Content-Disposition",  "filename=" + fileName);
client.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/" + extension);
client.post("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String response) {
          prgDialog.hide();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
            String content) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), statusCode,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

This always goes to the `onFailure` method with `statusCode 403`

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

status code 403 suggests that the request is forbidden.
Perhaps the folder you are uploading to the server doesn't have write permissions.

Comment: But when i m using same api in web to upload image... and there is no such problem.

Comment: is the api protected with some oAuth? 
could you share the response body and message ...

Comment: yes it has basic auth. but i have defined it... `client.setBasicAuth(username, password);`

the response is:
[{"data":{"status":403},"message":"You don't have permission to do this.","code":"rest_forbidden"}]